# Changing name when sending mail from same account in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Let's say my Gmail is `js@gmail.com`. Sometimes I want to send mail as `John`, and sometimes as `John Smith` from the same address.

Is there a way to do this without having to change the "Send mail as" settings every time?

Answer (score 1):

I think Premium Gmail supports email aliases. I think an email alias will address your problem. I dont think you can create email alias with the classic gmail account. Correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: You can use mail aliases in free Gmail (there is no Gmail premium actually (there is Google Apps Premium for your own domain to be precise)) but it's not possible to set actually two same addresses only with different name fields (not even in Google Apps Premium).

Answer (score 1):

Why change the "Send mail as" settings everytime ?

Just add yourself to the list

`js+work@gmail.com` where the display name can be John Smith.

The disadvantage here will be the appearance of your email address.

Now you can scroll between appearances within the "Compose Mail" section.